# How to login nextcloud via rest api?

Tags: nextcloud

Im very new to Nextcloud. I have a webapp has a login page. It has own authentication system. But I want to use Nextcloud’s authentication to login my webapp. So I want to take the username and password from my webapp then send it to Nextcloud via http request to get a token or something useful result about successful login.
I checked out documentation but couldnt find any info about getting token with rest api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Login Flow of the Nextcloud documentation. It details the old way of using usernames and passwords in the API or update to app passwords (apps can be registered and obtain a token)
https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual/client_apis/LoginFlow/index.html#converting-to-app-passwords